# How can I check if file is created between specified time?

Tags: python

How can I check if file is created between specified time?
E.g

```py
from datetime import datetime
import time
a = datetime.now()
b = a.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
c = "2020-11-04 17-00-00" 
if file.createdAt == betweenAandC:
    print("File created between A and C")
```

Comment: The datetime module has a timedelta object that can be added to or subtracted from a datetime, and datetimes can be compared with < and > etc.

Comment: Alternatively you could convert all the times to seconds since epoch (since 1970)  and just compare integers.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os 
a = datetime.now()
b = a.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
c = datetime(2020, 11, 4, 17)
fc = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime('FILE_PATH'))
if (fc < b) and (fc > c):
  # between range
```

Comment: fyi, python supports expressions like `c < fc < b`

Comment: Why do you convert `a` to a string? That will give a type-error when doing the comparison. And there is no need to use `strptime`: just do `c = datetime(2020, 11, 4, 17)`. The comparison should be `c < fc < a`.